# Update issue MS Access/C#

Tags: ms-access, insert-update

I have tried updateing the MS Database via c#. Although I haven't received any error, It doesn't update the database

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string UpdateQuery = "Update NDS Set IATACode=@p2,City=@p3,Country=@p4 where ID=@p1";
        OleDbCommand Update1 = new OleDbCommand(UpdateQuery, conn);
                Update1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtId.Text);
                Update1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtIata.Text);
                Update1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtCity.Text);
                Update1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txtCountry.Text);
                Update1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        ClearData();
        ShowData();
        MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    }
```

Comment: Do this base requires "commit" command after update/insert/delete queries?

Answer (score 0):

OLEDB doesn't support named parameters. You need to supply parameters in order:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    string UpdateQuery = "Update NDS Set IATACode=@p2,City=@p3,Country=@p4 where ID=@p1";
    OleDbCommand Update1 = new OleDbCommand(UpdateQuery, conn);
    Update1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtIata.Text);
    Update1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtCity.Text);
    Update1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txtCountry.Text);
    Update1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtId.Text);
    Update1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    ClearData();
    ShowData();
    MessageBox.Show("Updated");
}
```

Comment: Hi Erik. Thanks for your answer. I have the same parameters for SAVE button and it is working. Is your comment an exception for updating value?

Comment: Nope. Named parameters in queries should work nowhere, and are implicitly converted to ordered parameters. If, by chance, they're ordered correctly, it'll work of course. Else, I'd triple check you're not inserting values into the wrong field. The fact that this query didn't update anything is only due to the fact that it's filtered by a parameter.